# Not able to permitting params with rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a method that takes params from the request, and sorts the existing data, there is no saving involved, here is a method :

```
def forming_position
  nodes = params[:nodes_list].permit!
  nodes.each do |node|
    recursive_sorting node
  end
end
```

Here is relevant bit of method `recursive_sorting`:

```
def recursive_sorting(node, parent = nil)
  position = node[0]
  value = node[1]
  ......
end
```

The problem that I m having is that `.permit!` is either that I m using it wrong or not using correct method.

Here are my actual `params[:nodes_list]` :

```
params[:nodes_list]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"3"} permitted: true>, "2"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"2"} permitted: true>, "3"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

Here is the assigned `nodes` value :

```
nodes
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"3"} permitted: true>, "2"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"2"} permitted: true>, "3"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
nodes == params[:nodes_list]
=> true
```

When I am inside `forming_positions` method, inside each method that uses `node` as inner loop variable. And I inspect it's value. It is :

```
node
=> "1"
```

But when I inspect `nodes.first` element it gives me correct value:

```
nodes.first
=> ["1", <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"3"} permitted: true>]
```

**What is happening here?**

I need both key and a value in my `recursive_sorting` method, why is the node only getting passed around as a key only value. And what do I do to get both, was not sure if `permit!` is correct method to use here.

**Which method should I use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `params[:nodes_list]` is actually a hash, and method `each` works for hashes differently:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }.each do |key, value|
  p "#{key} => #{value}"
end
```

prints:

```
"a => 1"
"b => 2"
```

That's why you need to modify your code either:

```
def forming_position
  nodes = params[:nodes_list].permit!
  nodes.each do |position, value|
    recursive_sorting(position, value)
  end
end

def recursive_sorting(position, value, parent = nil)
  ......
end
```

Or:

```
def forming_position
  nodes = params[:nodes_list].permit!
  nodes.each do |position, value|
    recursive_sorting([position, value])
  end
end
```

Or:

```
def forming_position
  nodes = params[:nodes_list].permit!
  nodes.to_a.each do |node|
    recursive_sorting(node)
  end
end
```